# Simulate a SQL Azure environment locally

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I´m planning to migrate an existing application to Windows Azure. I know about a lot of changes in architecture I have to do in my code.

Today my application uses a SQL 2k5 database, and I wish to use the SQL Azure infrastructure as a replacement for the SQL Server. However, I haven´t found any kind of "SQL Azure Express", an application that can create locally an environment with the same (or almost the same) features those SQL Azure has. The question is: is there a server that a I can download it and run on my local server? Where I can find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no locally-installable SQL Azure. However, you can easily develop locally and point to a SQL Azure database in the cloud. If you have an MSDN subscription, you get a 1GB or 5GB database included, depending on [subscription](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/msdn-benefits/).

You can also develop against SQL Express locally, but this won't give you complete feature parity. You'd need to reference the [SQL Azure pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336279.aspx) to explore the differences between SQL Server and SQL Azure. You'd also want to run your local SQL Server / SQL Express database through the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/releases/view/32334) to spot differences.

Comment: This is the point, my database is relativelly large, and i wouldn´t like to subscribe the Azure till my system be stable.

Comment: For dev purposes, maybe you can work with a smaller db. If you stay under 1GB, you can get a 1GB (web edition) SQL Azure db for $9.99 / month, which, in the grand scheme of things, is very reasonable. This isn't locking you into any other costs, aside from bandwidth (at 0.14 / GB outbound, free inbound).

Answer (score 0):

Sql Azure database is a cloud database you cant really install it on local and use all its features you can any time use its api and connect from your local as David suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "SQL Azure Express". Basically your application uses sql azure exactly like a traditional sql server instance. According to microsoft you don't even need any modification to the database access part of your code.

However, your web application or NT service application may need some change to migrate to windows azure. Microsoft supplies a local develop environment.

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2019, it may be worth looking into using the Developer Edition of Sql Server instead of Express in certain situations - it's comparable to Enterprise in feaure-set, so you'll be able to run some of the other subsystems you might expect in a "live" (ie: Azure'd) setup.

Two main caveats:

- The feature-set and behaviours won't be identical to Azure. Basic workflows will be comparable - just make sure you're not developing using features that don't exist in the Azure SQL Databases.
- Make sure you're not trying to use it for Live systems - the free license is limited in scope.

See:

- [Onsite install versions - Feature Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Azure SQL vs SQL Server - Feature Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features)
- [Download links](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)

Comment: Hopefully after several years struggling with Azure we moved or workloads to AWS. SQL Azure was a kind of disgusting experience, while a full managed database environment is a dream, you have to deal with trouble neighbours, your execution plans cache, and your buffer sometimes are lost because of undetectable physical changes, and while that is invisible for you, it can degrade a lot your query performances. Beyond that, many connection drops, and bad performance for everything cheaper than premium gave us more reasons to leave Azure SQL.

Answer (score -2):

You can connect your sql azure database with SQL Server 2008 R2 only however there are many limitation on it. i was facing similar situation to maintain sql azure databse locally and i found some good client to manage that and it's RazorSQL , see my blog [here](http://www.arunrana.net/2011/11/razorsql-very-useful-client-to-manage.html) , it's paid but really useful tools